# Gravitational JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, gravity

Is there any good JQuery or JavaScript plugin that can be used to apply gravitation force effect on a particular DIV?

(example: google gravity)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at this Jquery plugin http://code.google.com/p/jqueryphysics/

Answer (score 6):

- http://weareallrobots.com/demos/gravity.html
- http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/simulate-gravity-with-jquery/